# TypeError: object is not a function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a 'Quote of the day' feature for a website. It works fine but I get a javascript error 'TypeError: object is not a function'.

```
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var output = '';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            $.post( "getquote.php?getjson", function( data ) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
                var data = JSON.parse(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                console.log(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                $.each(data, function(index, value){                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    output += '<p>'+value.quote+'</p>'; 
                }); 
                $('#qotd').html(output)('refresh');
            });
        });
```

The line that the error points at is:
`$('#qotd').html(output)('refresh');`

The code outputs a database record into the div tag with the id of qotd(quote of the day).

As I said, the code works perfectly so I must be missing something only slightly.

Comment: whta is the use of `refresh` in that line.?

Comment: If `'refresh'` is a custom event you want your application using, you'll want to use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) -- `$('#qotd').html(output).trigger('refresh');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need `refresh`? Simply remove it:

```
$('#qotd').html(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to ask refreshing when you change HTML contents, the browser will automatically do it for you. So, `$('#qotd').html(output);` is enough

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$('#qotd').html(output)('refresh')` with `$('#qotd').html(output);`.

You need to refresh, `jQuery` is already sexy to do this.